# NextGEN Gallery conflict with Roots Sage Theme

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery, roots-sage

I'm experiencing an issue with NextGEN where I'm unable to open 'Gallery Settings' or 'Other options' in the Wordpress dashboard. Many posts are saying to reset NGG settings, but I can't get into those areas. I'm also seeing that requests for NextGen assets like JS files are resulting in 404 errors because URL's are wrong/duplicate my domain.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that my issue stems from a Sage feature found in:

```
/mysagetheme/lib/setup.php
```

I ended up commenting out line 17 in the file:

```
//add_theme_support('soil-relative-urls');
```

I hope this helps someone avoid the same frustration.

Comment: I have been struggling with this for days! It was between the permalinks and that line right there. My hat is off to you. Thank you.

Comment: @DeFeNdog - You have saved the day good sir. I quickly found your solution and applied it. Thank you, thank you! Also, here's some info on the same topic in roots. https://discourse.roots.io/t/issue-nextgen-gallery-js-css-files-does-not-load-in-roots-sage-v9-base-part-of-url-is-doubled-other-templates-are-fine/8224